# Taylor expansion at discontinuous point

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, taylor-expansion

a) Find the Maclaurin expansion of the following function: $$f(x)=\int\limits_0^x \frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2} \mathrm{d}t$$
end b) evaluate the $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f^{(29)}\, (x) $

The above problem is from a past exam at calculus II (integral calculus) at my university.

How is it possible to express $ f(x) $as a Macluarin series since $ \displaystyle \frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2} $ does not exists for $ t_0=0 $?

so i would like to see some hints or\and solutions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually, $e^{-t^3}=1-t^3+o(t^3)$ for $t\to 0$ so the integrand function becomes $\frac{1-1+t^3+o(t^3)}{t^2}=t+o(t)$.

Comment: hint :$$e^{-t^3}=1-\frac{t^3}{1!}+\frac{t^6}{2!}-\frac{t^9}{3!}...\\\frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2}=\\\frac{1-(1-\frac{t^3}{1!}+\frac{t^6}{2!}-\frac{t^9}{3!}...)}{t^2}=\\t-\frac{t^4}{2!}+ \frac{t^7}{2!}...$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ 1-e^{-t}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}t^n\tag{1} $$
hence by replacing $t$ with $t^3$ and by dividing both terms by $t^2$ we get:
$$ \frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}t^{3n-2}\tag{2} $$
then, integrating termwise:
$$ \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2}\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(3n-1)n!}x^{3n-1}\tag{3}$$
we get the wanted Taylor series.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have another question, although $ \frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2}$ is not exists for $t_0=0$ the Taylor expansion is valid for $t_0=0$. Moreover $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2}=0$, which is the value of $ \frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2}$ as a Taylor expansion around zero. why is this happening?

Comment: The function $f(t)=\frac{1-e^{-t^3}}{t^2}$ has a removable discontinuity in zero, so we may just replace the integrand function with the same function defined as zero in the origin. The same happens for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, for instance.